# How to get body when status is not 200?

Tags: python, python-2.7, httprequest, tornado

I use something like this to send requests:

```
from tornado import httpclient
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPRequest

client = httpclient.HTTPClient()
request = HTTPRequest(url='http://google.com/', method="GET")
res = client.fetch(request)
print(res.body)
```

Works fine when HTTP status is 200 but I want to get the body always. How to handle this?

Comment: E.g. I might get a 401 - Unauthorized header but don't know the actual reason. Facebook API does things like that, I must check error code to handle different situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens when it returns a non-200 HTTP status? Does it throw an exception?
That is what happens according to [these](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html) docs. Is that true? In that case what you want to do is this:

```
from tornado import httpclient
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPRequest

    client = httpclient.HTTPClient()
    request = HTTPRequest(url='http://google.com/', method="GET")
    try:
        res = client.fetch(request)
        print(res.body)
    except HTTPError as err:
        res = err.response
        if res:
            print(res.body)
```